# Azure Data Factory - get input from copy data activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

How do I get the input of a copy activity?

I am using a copy activity, that executes a stored procedure, I want to retrieve the parameters that have been passed.

I can see in the JSON that it clearly stores the values, but how do I go about retrieving them?

[image: Pipeline Copy Data]

Example of parameters that are passed;

[image: Copy data input activity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, in ADF, there is no dynamic content for getting the input of the activity. You can see when I tried the below dynamic expression, I got the error saying that there is no property like `input`.

[image]

You can raise the feature request for that [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c).

As an alternative, try to get it using [Activity Runs - Query By Pipeline Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/activity-runs/query-by-pipeline-run?source=recommendations&tabs=HTTP#activityrun) REST API with a web activity.

For that, follow this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70100143/how-to-use-the-rest-api-for-activity-runs-in-azure-data-factory) by **@KarthikBhyresh-MT**.