# How to capture output query from ADF pipeline from For Each activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, pipeline, kql, azure-data-explorer

I have a pipeline on ADF with a `For Loop` activity and inside I have a `Data Flow` running a Kusto query. In this loop I am using a variable with 10 string in an array, so that my Data Flow will run based on those values as a parameter.

[image]

What is happening is, some of the runs in the loop is failing, and some others is working fine.

Example as image below:

[image]

How can I see the query that is running inside the Data Flow with all parameters and expression that I am using? I mean, the final query as an output. I would like to run that same query on my Kusto to see if something is wrong or not.

Based on @Rakesh Govindula answer, this is my data flow and this what I have tried from his answer:

[image]

Comment: How are you building the query? I mean are your creating the required query in the Dataflow parameters and using those directly as query? or just passing some values to the parameters and creating the query in the Dataflow source query using the combination of parameters and expressions?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula basically I am passing the values from For Each as a parameter to the Data Flow, then I am using that parameter along with other functions to build a string interpolation in the source query, using all those combinatios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataflow activity won't give the input query in its input or output. As a workaround try the below method.

Take a branch to your dataflow and use **derived column** transformation. In this create a column and **give the same query expression** to this.

You can add this by taking a branch to your current source or you can create another sample source and continue the same approach.

[image]

Here, I have taken SQL query for sample.

It will build the query and stores the query string in the column `query`. Use **cache sink** to know this query at pipeline level. The write order for this sink should be 1.

[image]

In the cache sink mapping, filter the `query` column using Rule based mapping like below.

[image]

In the Dataflow activity, set the logging to None and select first row only.

[image]

Now, you can find the input query in the Dataflow output cache sink.

[image]

Use the below expression to use this in the pipeline.

```
@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sinkCache.value[0].query
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the step by step instructions. But I got confused in some, in the cache sink mapping: did you keep only the derived column or all the columns? Setting the DF logging level to None instead of Verbose, I would lost some information when the pipeline runs? Where do I use expression in the last step and why?

Comment: In the cache sink I kept only the column from derived column transformation. Setting the logging level won't effect the data transformation and coming to the expression, if you want to use the query in the pipeline from the Dataflow, after dataflow activity, use that expression inside the loop.

Comment: I still don't get the step in the dataflow activity, do you mind adding more details and print please? Setting the logging level to None, would I lost some information in the input and output results? In the mapping, do I need to set the Input Columns as the name of the query or as you did `name==query`? Another thing is, if I set to `First row only`, the other "original" sink to ADLS that I have in the above branch, would be impacted? Do I need to know this query at pipeline level? I have updated my question to show my Data Flow

Comment: You won't lose any data in the actual sink, here you can see that the **first Row only** is only for the cache sink https://i.imgur.com/t61XGQx.png also, check the **Continue after sink error**, this is for even if an error occurs in a sink, it will continue processing the other sinks(cache sink). In the cache sink, you need to use Rule based mapping. First give the any column name in the derived column. In the sink cache sink, give the condition `name==query` which filters out the required column that we created in the dervied column.

Comment: Let me know if you are not getting it. I will update my answer tomorrow.

Comment: It worked when the pipeline succeeded, but not when the loop failed (I have the re-run enabled), so I was not able to get the query in the `Output` from a run. Even though the option `Continue after sink` is checked as your image.

Comment: I think you are getting the error in the source itself. If the source in the dataflow gives error, then the sink cache also won't work as it also starts from that source. If your ask to get the query even when the source is failing then AFAIK, It might not be possible in ADF. You can raise your idea as a feature request [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75533594/azure-data-factory-get-input-from-copy-data-activity/75547467#75547467).