# How to use output from a source in where clause on DataFlow ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, kql, azure-data-explorer

I have a dataflow that my source is a Kusto query. This source has over 100M rows which I am partition using a `hash` Kusto function from a `ForEach` activity.

In my Kusto query, one of the `where` clauses is to filter on the `SubscriptionId` field from a blob that is under my ADLSv2.

But, instead of using that solution hardcoded on my code, I would like to get those subscriptions from another Kusto query as another source (image below), but without using the `lookup` or `join` steps, because I need to filter the data in the source directly instead of projecting and then filtering. Otherwise, it might break/too much memory, etc.

**So, is it possible to filter in my main Kusto query in a where clause from the results of ANOTHER kusto source (aka CPCDevices)?**

This is my dataflow:

[image]

This is my main Kusto query as example:

```
Table
| project column1, column2, column3
| where SubscriptionId in ({CPCDevices})
//| another things on my query here..
```

The `CPCDevices` from the where clause is coming from the `CPCDecices source`

**UPDATE**

After adding another source, this is the dataflow updated with the QueryOutput derived columns as suggested in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77484174/how-to-capture-output-query-from-adf-pipeline-from-for-each-activity).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try **[Cache sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-sink#cache-sink)** here. But I haven't tested this for large data.

**This is my Table1 sample data:**

```
Id  Name    Age
1   Rakesh  22
2   Laddu   22
3   Virat   35
4   ABD     40
5   MSD     42
```

**Table2 sample data:**

```
Table2Id    Marks
1           94
3           100
5           98
```

Here I am projecting the columns `Id,Name` from `Table1` with a condition of `Id in Table2Id`.

First add a **cache sink** to the **Table2** source.

[image]

Now, use the cache sink [`outputs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#outputs) array in the source query of `Table1` like below.

```
"Table1| project Id,Name| where Id in (dynamic({map(sink1#outputs(),#item.Table2Id)}))"
```

[image]

Make sure your write order is `1` for the cache sink.

[image]

**Result of Table1 source:**

[image]

If the above approach is not working for the large data, then joins might be the best option here. First join the two tables in source KQL script itself and then project from the result table.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! In my other SO question, you helped me with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77485443/10176057), which I am able to output my query when pipeline succeeds. With this new solution from you, what should I adjust? Which one sink order should I define so I can see the Query Output + run query to get results + final and main sink?

Comment: The above flow is fine. Just add a derived column before the cache sink and give the expression for the query. Sink order for the cache sink should be 1 and other sink order should be 2.

Comment: As my image, I have 3 sinks. First one is the query output as you answered. Second one is the main output, and last one is this new source and cache sink. I have put this order as 1 source, 2 query and 3 results. But the query is not showing in the final output. How should I do please?

Comment: No need to use 3 sinks. Use 2 sinks, one for the sink cache and another for the main output. Give the sink cache sink to the table above source (In my case Table2) which you want to get the column. But before the sink cache add a derived column and give the query expression. Check the **write to activity output** checkbox in the sink cache. This sink cache will give the query column in the Dataflow activity output. Also, we can use the same sinkcache output within the dataflow expression using `sink1#outputs()` .array

Comment: Didn't work for me, because my cache results needs to be the query where I am going to pass the values to the main source. If I add a derived column and change the mapping as you told me to do in the other solution, the results will not be the same. Can you update your solution with new prints if possible please?

Comment: your cache will have 2 columns. One from the derived column and another is from the source which have values that need to check in another source KQL query. `dynamic({map(sink1#outputs(),#item.Table2Id)})` this expression, `#item.Table2Id` is the required column for the source query and in the dataflow activity sink cache output, you will get the query from the column of derived column transformation.

Comment: When I add a derived column into that source I am getting the error `Function outputs applis to only sink transformation with right saveOrder`.... `Higher other function cannot be evaluated with prior data types`

Comment: Can you provide your total dataflow image? with derived column expression

Comment: what is the write order for your sink cache?

Comment: Done! Let me know if you can understand please.

Comment: I think you are building the query with sink cache output values in the derived column itself. You can only build the normal query in derived column(here we cannot use sink cache output values because sink cache transformation is connected after the derived column). You can only use sink cache column values in another source but not in the derived column which is prior to the sink cache.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Because in the derived column itself there is no option to change from sink cache. I am building the normal query in both, and in the sink I am setting as cache as you suggested before. Because I don't need to save this output. Can you try on your end please? We can also move this discussion to a chat if you want, as SO is suggesting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256069/discussion-between-guilherme-matheus-and-rakesh-govindula).